# How to Center Align Share Buttons in Tumblr Posts

Tags: html, tumblr

I am trying to center align the twitter share and facebook share button to look in line with the rest of the layout design but I cannot figure out how to do that. My theme is the Eames Theme from Tumblr. I would like to have them spaced next to each other, center aligned. Thanks for any help!

www.alysonk.com

Here is my coding.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{Permalink}" data-text="      {PhotoAlt}" data-via="alysonkdotcom">Tweet</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for, but generally you can that with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k2cks/

For those looking for an answer without going to the jsfiddle:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="#">Tweet</a> <a href="#">Like</a>
</div>​
```

Basically, put a div around it and make the text align to the center with `text-align:center;`. Is this what you were looking for? Can you clarify?

**Edit:** another jsfiddle with an example similar to what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/k2cks/1/ You may also have to make the elements `display:inline;` to have them on the same line, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

put a `div` around the links and give the links a `display:inline;` style,

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{Permalink}" data-text="      {PhotoAlt}" data-via="alysonkdotcom">Tweet</a>
    <script>
        !function(d,s,id){
            var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
        }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>
    <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="verdana"></fb:like>
</div>
```

OR

(more complicated and roundabout but possibly helpful)

Try putting them inside of a `div` tag and giving that a styling it with `margin:0 auto 0 auto;width:INSERT WIDTH HERE;` and then style the links inside the div with `float:left;`.

You can also make this more visually helpful by giving the `div` a backgound color. And then you can take that off later.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto 0 auto; width:INSERT WIDTH HERE;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{Permalink}" data-text="      {PhotoAlt}" data-via="alysonkdotcom" style="float:left;">Tweet</a>
    <script>
        !function(d,s,id){
            var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
        }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>
    <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="verdana" style="float:left;"></fb:like>
</div>
```

**ANSWER UPDATE:**
I think that it might be tubmlr's issue with styling... You may not be able to fix it...
you could also try and give each of these elements a relative position and move them around until it works.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but it still doesn't work for me in tumblr. I cannot get the links to center align or float next to each other. how can i get this to work? what other info do you need from me to better understand what i am trying to accomplish. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple put your code inside of a `div` tag with `align="center"`

```
<div align="center">

"Your code mentioned above"

</div>
```

you can visit [my tumbler](http://murreepakistan.tumblr.com) to see addthis with align center.